# How do I style the React-Select component do get the following structure?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-select

I am trying to add some custom css to the React select component.

which is currently like,

```
<Select styles={styles} options={options} />
```

What I want to do is

[image]

What  I have implemented is like this

[image]

So, can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your style you will need to use a combination of custom `styles` and `components` like this:

```
const styles = {
  container: base => ({
    ...base,
    flex: 1
  }),
  control: base => ({
    ...base,
    boxShadow: '10px 10px 5px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.46)',
  }),
  indicatorSeparator: base => ({
    ...base,
    display: 'none'
  }),
  placeholder: base => ({
    ...base,
    color: 'blue'
  })
};

const Placeholder = (props) => {
  return (
    <components.Placeholder {...props}>
    None selected
    </components.Placeholder>
  );
};

<Select styles={styles} components={{Placeholder}} options={options} />
```

I think it's pretty close from what you put as example. Here a [live version](https://codesandbox.io/s/1z293ql077).